# Lookup type that partially satisfies union

Tags: typescript

Im trying to type a function that should accept 2 arguments. a sting (Union type) and an object.

The object keys should should extend the union. (but not necessarily everything in it).

My attempt below works if i pass a key for everything in my union but fails if some are missing.

Is this possible?

```js
export const csswitch = <O, K extends keyof O>(
  obj: O,
  key?: K
) => {
  if (key === undefined) return null
  return obj[key]
}


type CompProps = {
    size?: "s" | "m" | "l"
}

const Comp = ({ size }: CompProps) => {
 return csswitch({ s: '0.5rem', m: '1rem'}, size) // complains because 'l' is missing as a key in the object.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
export const csswitch = <K extends keyof any, O extends { [key in K]?: O[key]}>(
  obj: O,
  key?: K
) => {
  if (key === undefined) return null
  return obj[key]
}
```

It should be right.